# postgresql create user on osx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bash, postgresql, path

I'm on osx and I have problems creation of user postgresql.
when I write the command:

```
createuser myapp -s
```

I get the following error:

```
could not connect to database postgres: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
Is the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket "/var/pgsql_socket/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

I do not know if it's just PATH directory problem.

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
```

I installed postgresql with this solution : http://tammersaleh.com/posts/installing-postgresql-for-rails-3-1-on-lion

thanks for your help and sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure the postgres server is running? (Use "ps ax | grep postgres"). Has it opened a TCP port (per default 5432)? Is this unix socket "/var/pgsql_socket/.s.PGSQL.5432" available and do you have the permissions to read/write it?

Furthermore, you may want to check the pg_hba.conf file where the permissions on the postgres server itself are configured.